# python -m <module_name> works but directly using module_name in the cmd line doesn't work

Tags: python

If I try to run commands like `pytest`, `pip` or `locust`, example: `pytest <filename.py>`, it doesn't work. But if I do `python -m pytest <filename.py>` it works. Same thing for `pip`, `locust` or any module. What can I do so that I can directly use the module instead of having to write `python -m module` everytime?
I tried to set path of `pip`, what it seems to be all right. My expectation is that it should work directly with the module name instead of having to write the complete command like `python -m <module_name>`

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add the info from your comments on the now-deleted answer? If you don't have access, I can retrieve the answer and comments for you, just LMK.

Comment: Does this help? [how to fix 'auto-py-to-exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](/questions/67851955/how-to-fix-auto-py-to-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command). I don't use Windows myself, but this looks like a similar situation and the answers look good. The one about the `PATH` is probably the one you want.

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment?